# How to solve this equation $2.02(T+25)^{5/4}+1.15*10^{-8} (T+273)^4=203.54$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

How to solve this equation

$2.02(T+25)^{5/4}+1.15*10^{-8} (T+273)^4=203.54$

Here the value of T may lie between -100 to 100 .

The binomial expansion is tedious.

Comment: It looks alot like numerics anyways, so I suggest using a numerical solver (for example "lsqnonlin" from MATLAB)
$$$$
//EDIT// W|A says $$T\approx 3.98466$$ if that helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the function $f:[-100,100] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $$f(T)=2.02 \times (T+25)^{5/4}+1.15 \times 10^{-8} \times (T+273)^4-203.54.$$  We want to find solutions to $f(T)=0$.

Since we want $f(T)$ to be real, we require $T+25 \geq 0$, i.e., $T \geq -25$.  So, we can restrict the domain of $f$ to obtain a real-valued function $g:[-25,100] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(T)=f(T)$.

We observe:

- $g$ is continuous and increasing,
- $g(3.98)<0$, and
- $g(3.99)>0$.

(The latter two observations are made computationally.)

Thus $g$ has a single (real) root between $3.98$ and $3.99$.

*Note*: this root is unlikely to have a simple closed-form formula, since it would be a root of a degree $16$ polynomial (which is unlikely to have "easy" linear factors to factor out).

Comment: Rebecca, 2.5k reputation in two weeks? You need to get a life:)

Answer (score 0):

If you plot the function, you identify that the solution is close to zero. Then, use Newton's method. Starting from 0, the iterates will successively be 4.06274, 3.98468, 3.98466, 3.98466.